# DIstinct Serial Number with value updates

Tags: sqlite, distinct

Hello thanks for accepting my question, i have below data collected from sensors and i need to get **only latest changes** from all data, i am using sqlite with sqliteStuidio, please help me with the query that i can use to get Expected data.
thanks in advance.
Please see the image as table is not properly formatted.
[data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1HXt.png)

Input data :

| Serial | Key | Time_Stamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12 | 20230531010945 | 1 |
| 0 | 11 | 20230531010912 | 0 |
| 0 | 10 | 20230531010657 | 1 |
| 0 | 9 | 20230531010648 | 0 |
| 1 | 8 | 20230531010551 | 1 |
| 1 | 7 | 20230531010539 | 0 |
| 1 | 6 | 20230531010521 | 0 |
| 0 | 5 | 20230531010346 | 0 |
| 0 | 4 | 20230531000935 | 1 |
| 0 | 3 | 20230531000928 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 20230531000724 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 20230531000652 | 1 |

Expected Data :

| Serial | Key | Time_Stamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12 | 20230531010945 | 1 |
| 1 | 8 | 20230531010551 | 1 |

So far i have tried some combinations but failed...

```
SELECT sensor_data.[sensor_serial], sensor_data.[key],sensor_data.[time], sensor_data.[value]
FROM sensor_data
WHERE sensor_serial = (SELECT  sensor_serial FROM sensor_data)
ORDER BY time DESC
```

its output is :

```
0   12  20230531010945  1
0   11  20230531010912  0
0   10  20230531010657  1
0   9   20230531010648  0
0   5   20230531010346  0
0   4   20230531000935  1
0   3   20230531000928  0
0   1   20230531000652  1
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM yourtable GROUP BY serial HAVING MAX(time_stamp)` ?

Comment: Thank you so much, SELECT * FROM yourtable GROUP BY serial HAVING MAX(time_stamp), it worked just fine as expected<br> Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done as follows :

First we identify max time per sensor_serial using `group by` and `max()` :

```
select sensor_serial, max(time) as max_time
from sensor_data
group by sensor_serial
```

Then join this dataset with the table :

```
select sd.*
from sensor_data sd
inner join (
  select sensor_serial, max(time) as max_time
  from sensor_data
  group by sensor_serial
) as s on s.sensor_serial = sd.sensor_serial and s.max_time = sd.time
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/bKcJTBWz)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT *
FROM [sensor_data]
WHERE [time] IN
    (SELECT MAX([time])
    FROM [sensor_data]
    GROUP BY [sensor_serial]);
```

Or with Common Table Expression:

```
WITH CTE_Top (maxtime)
AS
    (SELECT MAX([time])
    FROM [sensor_data]
    GROUP BY [sensor_serial])
SELECT [sensor_serial], [key], [time], [value]
FROM [sensor_data]
INNER JOIN CTE_top ON [time] = [maxtime];
```

If several records may have exactly the same timestamp but the key is unique, then you can try:

```
WITH CTE_Top (maxkey)
AS
    (SELECT MAX([key])
    FROM [sensor_data]
    GROUP BY [sensor_serial])
SELECT [sensor_serial], [key], [time], [value]
FROM [sensor_data]
INNER JOIN CTE_top ON [key] = [maxkey];
GO
```

Comment: This is wrong: https://dbfiddle.uk/TU4kguxe

Comment: The 2nd is also wrong: https://dbfiddle.uk/9vlnwONg

Comment: @forpas In your example there is twice the same time. I have supposed that the time is unique as in the example data. sanjeev kumar: are two records possible at exactly the same time?

Comment: *are two records possible at exactly the same time?* why not if they represent different sensors?

Comment: @forpas : Technically yes, two data can come as same time of course

Comment: @jhnc but this works even if the time is same for two data <br> SELECT * FROM yourtable GROUP BY serial HAVING MAX(time_stamp) ? – 
jhnc
 3 hours ago

Comment: @sanjeevkumar *but this works even if the time is same for two data* this is coincidental. The logic of the queries is wrong.